# Get deepest nested path (files and then directory)

Tags: python, windows, directory, nested

Consider the following tree:

```
bin\ [directory]
--- file.ext
bin\a [directory]
--- file.bin
--- file2.bin
--- file3.bin
--- anotherDir\ [directory]
-------------- image.png
-------------- image1.png
-------------- image2.png
-------------- image3.png
-------------- image4.png
bin\b [directory]
--- xyz.etc
--- xyz.etc
--- zyx.etc
--- deepDir\ [directory]
-------------- image.tif
-------------- image1.tif
-------------- deepestDir\ [directory]
------------------------- something.exe
------------------------- app.exe
```

What I want to do is to get (print for now) the deepest available files and after it their directory name.

So consider this directory which is the deepest:

```
-------------- deepestDir\ [directory]
------------------------- something.exe
------------------------- app.exe
```

First I want to print relative path to:

- app.exe
- something.exe
- then print containing directory which will be `bin\b\deepDir\deepestDir`

After that, the next deepest would be:

```
--- deepDir\ [directory]
-------------- image.tif
-------------- image1.tif
```

So print:

- image.tif
- image1.tif
- containing directory which will be 'bin\b\deepDir' in this case

[..] and so on up to the main directory `.`

I have tried several possibilities and ended up on this:

```
# First, collect ALL files:
SEARCH_PATH = "E:\\project\\elohim\\"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SEARCH_PATH):
    for file in files:
        relativePath = os.path.relpath(root, SEARCH_PATH)
        if relativePath == ".":
            relativePath = ""

        print 'File: {}'.format(os.path.join(relativePath, file))

# Then collect DEEPEST subdirectories
subDirs = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SEARCH_PATH):
    subDirs.append(os.path.relpath(root, SEARCH_PATH))

subDirs.sort(lambda x, y: cmp(x.count(os.path.sep), y.count(os.path.sep)), reverse=True)

for k in subDirs:
     print 'Directory: {}'.format(k)
```

Actually it's not what I want, however - it's really close (its first searching for all files in a directory and then for deepest subdirectories).

(So what I'm having right now is for example):

```
- image.png
- image1.png
- image2.png
- image3.png
- image4.png
- xyz.etc
- xyz.etc
- zyx.etc
- image.tif
- image1.tif
[..]
and then directories:
bin\b\deepDir\deepestDir
bin\b\deepDir
bin\b
bin
```

Its its not clear enough, let me know, I will try to explain as best as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
import os
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

SEARCH_PATH = "E:\\project\\elohim\\"

all_files = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(SEARCH_PATH):
    for file in files:
        relativePath = os.path.relpath(root, SEARCH_PATH)
        if relativePath == ".":
            relativePath = ""
        all_files.append(
            (relativePath.count(os.path.sep),
             relativePath,
             file
             )
        )

all_files.sort(reverse=True)

for (count, folder), files in groupby(all_files, itemgetter(0, 1)):
    print('Directory:', folder)
    for file in files:
        print('File:', file[2])
```

You traverse the tree twice. Not really necessary. The code essentially creates a list of tuples. Each tuple contains the depth, the relative path,  and the filename.

After that the list is sorted to have the deepest folder(s) first.

Following that the code groups the files by depth and relative path. I am using the `groupby` method of the `itertools` method.

From there it is easy to print the stuff and any order you like.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks a ton.